# Convert anonymous object to expression delegate

Tags: c#

I have an third party library that has the following API:

```
 Update<TReport>(object updateOnly, Expression<Func<TReport,bool>> where)
```

What I want to do is call this method but using anonymous objects such as :

```
Update(new {Name = "test"}, new {Id = id})
```

Is it possible to take the second anonymous object and convert it to something like :

```
x => x.Id == id.
```

So what I want is to convert the new {Id = id} to a function that takes TReport and returns bool?

Comment: why? this would be complex and loose the intended meaning. It would also lose `TReport`

Comment: Reason I want to do this is I have an interface that accepts Update(object, object) and I want to keep that interface (so I do not break the clients), but swap out the implementation to adapt another class that uses the expression function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if I agree with Daniel A. White on the fact that it's complicating things, I tried a bit.

But it's not safe, cause you're `losing strong typing`. (You can put whatever you want in an anonymous object : it's not linked to the object's "real" properties... So no refactoring, no check...)

It's not really tested, so not sure if that's what you want. You can have (if it works) different objects in the "predicate object" :

```
new {Name="test"}, new{Id=1, Name="test2"})
```

So, you could have something like that :

```
public static class MyHelpers
{
        public static Expression<Func<TReport, bool>> CreatePredicate<TReport>(this object predicateObject)
        {
            var parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TReport), "item");
            Expression memberExpression = parameterExpression;
            var objectDictionary = MakeDictionary(predicateObject);
            foreach (var entry in objectDictionary.Where(entry => typeof(TReport).GetProperty(entry.Key) == null))
            {
               throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Type {0} has no property {1}", typeof(TReport).Name, entry.Key));
            }
            var equalityExpressions = GetBinaryExpressions(objectDictionary, memberExpression).ToList();
            var body = equalityExpressions.First();
            body = equalityExpressions.Skip(1).Aggregate(body, Expression.And);

            return Expression.Lambda<Func<TReport, bool>>(body, new[] { parameterExpression });
        }
        private static IDictionary<string, object> MakeDictionary(object withProperties)
        {
            var properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(withProperties);
            return properties.Cast<PropertyDescriptor>().ToDictionary(property => property.Name, property => property.GetValue(withProperties));
        }

        private static IEnumerable<BinaryExpression> GetBinaryExpressions(IDictionary<string, object> dic, Expression expression)
        {
            return dic.Select(m => Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(expression, m.Key), Expression.Constant(m.Value)));
        }
}
```

usage, for example

```
public void Update<TReport>(object updateOnly, object predicateObject) {
   var predicate = predicateObject.CreatePredicate<TReport>();
   yourGenericApi.Update(updateOnly, predicate);
}
```

EDIT :
As you're losing strong typing security, you should add something like

```
foreach (var entry in objectDictionary.Where(entry => typeof(TReport).GetProperty(entry.Key) == null))
{
    throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Type {0} has no property {1}", typeof(TReport).Name, entry.Key));
}
```

after

```
var objectDictionary = MakeDictionary(predicateObject);
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you so much. I would not go this way if I did not have to change my clients but at least I have a solution. I will have to spend a few hours and work out how you did it :)

Comment: @JD. In fact, you face 2 dangers while going to anonymous object : 1. Property Name doesn't exist in the object (throwing exception in my Edit) / 2. Value of the anonymous object is wrong :`new{Id="asdf"}`, even is Property Id in object is an int. That's not managed in my code.

Comment: Okay, thanks for that. At the moment I will have to see how much work is involved to change the clients. If it is too much then maybe I will use your solution with the changes. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a specific value that you want the function to return, I think you can simply do this:

```
bool desiredResult = true;
Update(new { Name = "test" }, x => desiredResult);
```

Comment: What meaning does it lose?  It may be that the questioner has a case where they always want the boolean result to be a particular value regardless of the instance of `TResult`.  That's not meaningless; it's just that we can't *see* the meaning from the snippet of code provided.

Comment: I think the OP wants the object to be converted to the expression.